# Sending files via scrapy JsonRequest

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to send a file using scrapy JsonRequest object to an API built using DRF. Currently I am using the requests module but that defeats the purpose of asynchronous scraping.

Specifications:

```
Scrapy==1.8.0
Django==3.0.3
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

Current solution:

```
requests.post(
    url = 'API_URL',
    files = {'document': open(doc_name, 'rb')}
)
```

I have tried using this method:

```
yield JsonRequest(
    url = 'API_URL',
    callback = self.document_downloaded,
    data = {
        'document': open(doc_name, 'rb')
    }
)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'BufferedReader' is not JSON serializable
```

Is there any other way of passing a file to the API? Or maybe just sending the binary data of the file from the spider to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert the image into base64 string and then get this string in
   Python file then decode and then save in folder